# I am trying to deploy the microsoft fluid framework on Aws eks cluster but the pods go in to CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, amazon-eks, fluid-framework

When I get the logs for one of the pods with the CrashLoopBackOff status

`kubectl logs alfred`

it returns the following errors.

```
error: alfred service exiting due to error {"label":"winston","timestamp":"2021-11-08T07:02:02.324Z"}
```

```
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'mongodb'
} {"label":"winston","timestamp":"2021-11-08T07:02:02.326Z"}
```

```
error: Client Manager Redis Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis {"errno":"ENOTFOUND","code":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"redis","stack":"Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26)","label":"winston","timestamp":"2021-11-08T07:02:02.368Z"}
```

I am new to the Kubernetes and Aws Eks. Would be looking forward to help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors above were being generated because mongo and redis were not exposed by a service. After I created service.yaml files for the instances the above errors went away. Aws Eks deploys containers in pods which are scattered across different nodes. In order to let mongodb communicate from one pod to another you must expose a service or aka "frontend" for the mongodb deployment.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the error its failing at getaddrinfo, which is a program/function to resolve the dns name and connect with an external service. It is trying to access a redis cluster. Seems like your EKS cluster doesn't have the connectivity.

However if you are running redis as part of your EKS cluster, make sure to provide/update the kubernetes service dns in the application code, or set this as an environment variable which can be set just before deployment.

Its redis and mongodb, also as error says you are providing hostname as redis and mongodb, it won't resolve to an IP address unless you have mapped it in /etc/hosts file which is actually untrue.

Give the correct hostnames, the pods will come up. This is the root-cause.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. There is one more thing that I noticed. The mongodb and redis pods are running fine in seperate nodes where as the dependent microservices are deployed in different pods which are in different nodes. So basically can it be because of pods in different nodes can't connect to each other? I'll have a look at your solution as well.

Comment: Alright now its fine and clear that redis+mongodb are a type of deployment which are running in the k8s cluster itself. So do a kubectl get service and then provide the service dns of each with the port used as part of the hostname field. This will fix your issue.

Comment: This is the service file for alfred: 
```apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.24.0 (4a2a0458)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: alfred
  name: alfred
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "3003"
      port: 3003
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: alfred
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```
This is the 

```kubectl get service```
  
response

```NAME  TYPE  CLUSTER-IP EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)  AGE
    alfred   ClusterIP   10.100.225.183   <none>  3003/TCP  17h```

Comment: ```mongodb-1636272258   ClusterIP   10.100.3.47      <none>        27017/TCP   29h```

Comment: Your service spec selector is selecting itself. You need to post your deployment and service spec **to your question**, don't post it in the comment as it is very difficult to read.

Comment: I think I got you, This is how you are asking me to do? 
```apiVersion: v1 
kind: Pod 
metadata: 
  name: busybox1
  labels:
    name: busybox
spec:
  hostname: busybox-1
  subdomain: default-subdomain
  containers:
  - image: busybox:1.28
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    name: busybox```

Comment: By default eks doesnot resolve hostnames to the pods. The above example will let me assign the pod with a hostname. I think @redzack is right. I will check this now.